# firebase configuration for v10

Tags: javascript, firebase

how do i properly configure my firebase for v10 cus this is giving me a syntax error and here is what it said Uncaught SyntaxError: The requested module '/node_modules/.vite/deps/firebase_app.js?v=1c73ee04' does not provide an export named 'default' (at firebase.jsx:24:8) but here is my code

```
import firebase from 'firebase/app';
import 'firebase/auth';
import 'firebase/firestore';

// Your Firebase configuration
const firebaseConfig = {
  apiKey: "AIzaSyCx2yjPuTi4nSWVrnXHg3KibdcwQ2HJqyY",
  authDomain: "instagram-yt-d1e1e.firebaseapp.com",
  projectId: "instagram-yt-d1e1e",
  storageBucket: "instagram-yt-d1e1e.appspot.com",
  messagingSenderId: "743305877307",
  appId: "1:743305877307:web:f152c6e75ab60b7b87c91e"
};

// Initialize Firebase app
firebase.initializeApp(firebaseConfig);

// Get Firebase service instances
const auth = firebase.auth();
const db = firebase.firestore();

// Server timestamp (optional)
const FieldValue = firebase.firestore.FieldValue.serverTimestamp;

// Exports (consider renaming 'firebase' for clarity)
// eslint-disable-next-line react-refresh/only-export-components
export { auth, db, FieldValue };
```

tried configuring my firebase to send in information to my firebase backend

Comment: Did you see https://firebase.google.com/docs/web/modular-upgrade and https://firebase.google.com/docs/web/setup?

Answer (score 0):

It seems like your imports is the issue. Try something like this:

```
import firebase from 'firebase/app';
import * from 'firebase/auth';
import * from 'firebase/firestore';
```

Comment: still not working as the version i am making use of is v10 and above